# Copy a directory with SAS EG

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

Is it possible to copy a directory in SAS EG
Every day when I run my SAS job I have to manually copy a folder on my harddrive.
S:\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Daglig LCR - Axiom\Daglig LCR\2022\12\2022-20-12

The path is bulit like this:
2022: year
12: month
2022-20-12: date

Is it possible for SAS EG to copy the contents of the folder "2022-20-12" and create a new folder with the name "2022-21-12" containning all the contents of the old folder.

Comment: Is the SAS session that your Enterprise Guide project is using running on a machine that has access to the files?   Does it have the XCMD option enabled so that you can run operating system commands from within SAS?

Comment: @Tom I am not sure if XCMD is enabled. But I can open and edit excel and csv files on the computer. So maybe does XCMD make this operation easier?

Answer (score 1):

I've linked a paper below which has all the necessary steps in.  The code is quite long so it wouldn't be worth copying into here but the rest of the paper may help you with other things too.

To perform the action you're looking for:

1. **%sys_find** all directories and files within your given root source directory (this uses the %sys_ls macro)
2. Replace all old file/directory names with new paths.  Output files to one dataset, directories to another
3. Store all directories to create into macro variables
4. **%sys_dir_create** the directory structure recursively downwards
5. Store all source filenames and target filenames to copy into macro variables
6. **%sys_file_copy** all the files from their old location to their new one

For step 2, to translate the path/file names you'd use:
new_var = tranwrd(**varname**, *old_root_path*, *new_root_path)*

You can review the macros in the paper and even remove a lot of checks which go on to just include your individual steps if need be which would shorten it down a lot.  You'd still need to %sys_find logic to get a source list but the directory and file creation you could in one step if you wanted to.

https://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/support/en/sas-global-forum-proceedings/2020/5115-2020.pdf